# How do you center a flat list with flex=1 items and not shrink the content while keeping a full width?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am trying to set up a flat list with items having the following properties.

- it has `flex: 1`
- it has no specified width (the height may be set in the content for images)
- it is `maxWidth` set
- the `width` cannot be forced to `100%` because the intent is to have the flat list support multiple columns
- `minWidth` cannot be set since it will prevent shrinking of content if it is too large to fit with number of columns.

The `FlatList` is the top level component of a Screen so it will do the collapsing header in iOS. To which

- it takes up the full width
- it has some padding
- the scroll bar should be flushed right (so you can't do `padding` on the FlatList itself

So what I have is something like

```
const data = Array.from({length: 5}, (v,k) => ({v,k}));
function renderItem({item, index}) {
  return (<View style={{
    flex:1, 
    maxWidth: 100, 
    borderWidth: 1, 
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    // alignSelf: "center" (also shrinks)
  }}>
    <Text>{item.k}</Text>
  </View>)
}

return (<FlatList
  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
  contentContainerStyle={{
    padding: 16,
    // alignSelf: center (shrinks content)
  }}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  data={data}
/>)
```

I'd also like to avoid `onLayout` to prevent too much rerenders

https://snack.expo.dev/@trajano/flatlistneedscentering

Comment: you mean like this [snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/l5r09rtji)

Comment: the snack you're showing shows that the items are being shrunk.  I want to keep it the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another prop called `columnWrapperStyle` which does what I needed.

```
    <FlatList
      columnWrapperStyle={{
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingVertical: 16,
      }}
      initialNumToRender={2}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={data}
      numColumns={numColumns} //can be set to 3 to force shrinking
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.k.toString()}
    />
  );
```

Note that NativeBase does not expose this as a utility prop.